# Is Platinum End meant to refer to the Biblical story of Elijah (1 Kings 19:4-7) who was suicidal and God sent an angel?

Tags: platinum-end

Also asked on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/platinumend/comments/r7qgxl/is_platinum_end_meant_to_refer_to_the_biblical/).

Re Elijah:

1. http://web.mit.edu/jywang/www/cef/Bible/NIV/NIV_Bible/1KGS+19.html
2. https://ibpf.org/the-prophet-elijah-was-depressed/
3. https://bible.org/seriespage/15-crisis-elijah-1-kings-194-14
4. https://wordsbymatthew.com/blog/7-lessons-depression-elijah-suicidal-prophet
5. https://believehim.org/how-god-dealt-with-elijahs-depression/

I looked up just now "platinum end" "elijah" but wasn't able to find anything (except [the obvious](https://www.reddit.com/r/platinumend/comments/r7qgxl/is_platinum_end_meant_to_refer_to_the_biblical/)). Is Platinum End supposedly a reference to Elijah specifically? Or is this some common thing in religion or mythology, where a deity sends an angel to a suicidal person? (Of course we are very blessed that deities send angels to us everyday through our struggles in life, esp during this pandemic. These angels are what we call some fellow humans.)

Comment: I note that you've [cross-posted to SFF:SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258387/is-platinum-end-meant-to-refer-to-the-biblical-story-of-elijah-1-kings-194-7). If you want to have that question running there (so soon), you need to delete it from here;

Comment: @Richard i think it's ok. someone hopefully is about to answer using 'it's a wonderful life'

Comment: @Richard re 'note', why note when i've already mentioned in the OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was mentioned by another user ([Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum), who is free to post h own answer) that that angels' appearing to suicidal humans is a pretty common trope in fiction, for example in the 1946 film [It's a Wonderful Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Wonderful_Life).

Perhaps it's more appropriate to ask not if the movie or the trope in general originates from the story of Elijah, which of course would be the subject for another post.